# face recognition as password

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung

Looking for an application that use face recognition of the cellphone's owner wnen you are powering on your cellphone + activating the phone after being stand by with black screen.

Where can I find it?

I'm using Galaxy SII with android 4

Answer (score 2):

Is it face unlock you are asking about? If so, there is a handy guide [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-setup-face-unlock-on-galaxy-s2-ics-android-4-0-44247/). It requires your phone to be rooted and have ClockworkMod Recovery installed. Here are the installation instructions from the link:

> Installation Instructions
>
> Before you proceed with setting up Face Unlock on your Galaxy S2, make
>   sure that your phone:
>
> is rooted, has ClockworkMod Recovery installed, and is running Android
>   4.0.3 Ice Cream Sandwich firmware build XXKP8.
>
> If your phone meets those requirements, you can follow these steps:
>
> 1.Download the Face Unlock update file to your computer and then copy the downloaded ZIP file to your SD card. Get the file here.
>
> 2.Turn off your mobile phone and reboot it into recovery mode. You can do this by pressing the Volume Up and OK buttons. Press both buttons
>   at the same time and then press the Power button.
>
> 3.If you are already in recovery mode, proceed by selecting “Wipe data/factory reset” and “Wipe Cache partition”.
>
> 4.Reboot your device by selecting “Reboot system now” from the recovery menu.
>
> 5.Reboot your device again into recovery mode.
>
> 6.From the menu, select “install zip from SD card”, then ” choose zip from SD card”, and then choose the Face Unlock ZIP file which is on
>   your phone. After you have selected the file, installation will start.
>
> 7.After installation, your device will again display the recovery mode screen. Select “Reboot system now” to reboot the phone. Take note that
>   this time, restarting your device will take much longer. On the other
>   hand, you can also opt to update this package from ClockworkMod
>   Recovery.